# Declarar variables sin tener una cantidad definida javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Hola en la escuela nos están enseñando javascript y nos pusieron un problema que era crear un programa que sumara números hasta que el usuario apretara "x". Mi duda es como hago si no se cuantas variables van a hacer y como hago que el programa termine cuando el usuario apriete "x".

Comment: Crea un arreglo vacío y le vas dando "push". Esto te será de ayuda: http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javascriptya/ y la documentación de Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia Por cierto, bienvenido a SOes, recuerda visitar https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla, del mismo modo revisa cómo preguntar aquí : https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Con esto, evitarás que te den negativos, tu pregunta necesita código y mostrar las cosas que has intentado para que tenga calidad :)

Comment: Agrega codigo de ejemplo para poder conocer tu problema y de esa forma que la comunidad te ayude con tu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que esto te sirva como guía

```
// Declaramos un array donde guardaremos nuestros numeros
var inputs = [] 
// Ejecutamos un ciclo do-while que a diferencia del while, este hará la primera ejecución
do{
// Preguntamos por un numero con un prompt
var input = prompt('Ingrese un numero')
// verificamos que lo ingresado no sea el caracter de salida del ciclo, si no es el 
// caso lo agregamos a nuestro array
if(input != 'x'){
     inputs.push(input)
 }
}while(input != 'x')
// Mostramos todos los numeros que hay disponibles en el array
console.log("Numeros ingresados:", inputs)
```

El ciclo do-while te permitirá preguntar por N numeros hasta que se ingrese el caracter x, que permitirá salir del ciclo.

Para sumar y obtener los numeros mayores y menores puedes guiarte del siguiente código, que debería ir a continuación del interior.

```
var inputs = [5000, 100, -100, 50]

// Inicializamos las variables para asignar nuestros valores,
// lo hacemos fuera del ciclo por que no necesitamos que
// se instancien y sobrescriban en cada iteración,
// además si no hay elementos a recorrer tendremos 
// valores por defecto controlados

var min = 'No existe'
var max = 'No existe'
var sum = 0

// Recorremos el array de objetos y en la primera iteración
// guardamos el primer numero como mayor y menor.
// en las siguiente iteraciones vamos comparando los siguientes
// numeros que se van iterando, si es menor al menor que tenemos
// almacenado, lo sobrescribimos, así siempre iremos teniendo
// el numero menor en nuestra variable min a medida que va
// iterando el ciclo. Lo mismo pasa con el mayor
inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
        // Acá simplemente vamos sumando todos valores que se
    // van iterando
    sum += input
        // en la primera iteración, asignamos el valor
    if(index == 0){
        min = input
        max = input
    }else{
    // comparamos los valores y sobrescribimos si es necesario
        if(input > max){
        max = input
        }
        if(input < min){
            min = input
        }
    }
})

// Mostramos los resultados
console.log("Minimo", min)
console.log("Maximo", max)
console.log("Suma", sum)`
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias hoy se lo he enseñado a mi profe y me ha dicho que esta bien lo que me siguió causando problemas fue que me dijo que ahora quiere que el programa me diga la suma de los números ingresados, cual fue el mayor y cual fue el menor busque por la web pero no me salio te adjunto un link al codigo https://pastebin.com/TkK7aqaa disculpa que no lo ponga aqui la verdad es que no se como poner el codigo. Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, espero pueda ayudarte como guía. recuerda que te estás formando como un profesional y la idea acá es que logres comprender el código, no te hacemos un favor con entregarte la respuesta, por el contrario.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer utilizando la función setInterval() para llamar una función cada segundo y esta este sumando y cuando el usuario presione x se limpie el llamado de la función con clearInterval, el siguiente código te puede servir.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Título</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p id="etiquetaPSumar"></p>

<script>
    var valorsumar=0;
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {  
    if(e.keyCode==120|| e.keyCode==88){
        clearInterval(refreshConatdor);
    }
    console.log(e.keyCode); 

});

function contador(){
    document.getElementById("etiquetaPSumar").innerHTML  = valorsumar;
    valorsumar++;
}
var refreshConatdor = setInterval(contador,1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```